# Ordinal vs. Hierarchical Logistic Regression

Tags: matlab, prediction, logistic-regression, hierarchical, ordinal

I am attempting to predict the ranking of NBA teams next season based on the number of games they won this season. To do this, I thought I could use a logistic regression with historical data. As stated, my dependent variable is following season ranking, and my independent variable is current season ranking. For example, the Golden State Warriors had 36 wins in 2010-11, and they finished the 2011-12 season with the 24th best record in the league, and these 2 data points would serve respectively as my IV and DV.

My ultimate goal is to figure out what the odds are of a team that wins 35 games in the current season to have a top-10 record in the following season. Is logistic regression the best way to handle this problem? If so, is it ordinal or hierarchical? The MATLAB code I have been using is below:

`B = mnrfit(X,Y)
pihat = mnrval(B,35)`

where X is the current wins and Y is next season's ranking. I then summed the first 10 values of `pihat` to get my probability.

Is there a better way to be going about this? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Seems like a better fit for [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com).